# How to congig the setting of local reposity before start a sping boot web service?

Tags: java

It appears when i'm starting the spring boot service? May be there are something wrong with the settings of local reposity!But how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You need to provide some info about the problem. What exactly are you trying to do? What error do you get? Post some stack trace of error log, anything ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.